# Android: Programmatically pair bluetooth device

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, pairing

I'm trying to programmatically pair a phone to a bluetooth device. Although I am able to do so, a window still pops up asking the user to enter the PIN.
Is there any way to hide this window?

What I'm doing:

Getting a `BluetoothDevice` object of the target;

Attempt to create a bond:

```
 Class class1 = Class.forName("android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice");
 Method createBondMethod = class1.getMethod("createBond");
 createBondMethod.invoke(device);
```

Listening to `BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST` I attempt to set the Pin:

```
Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("setPin", byte[].class);
m.invoke(device, pin);
device.getClass().getMethod("setPairingConfirmation", boolean.class).invoke(device, true);
```

Although I am aware Android might not give us this option due to malicious software, I'd very much like to hide the window that asks for the PIN (it's not necessary because the bonding is complete even when the user doesn't enter any data into that window) since my app targets kids, they might not be able to complete the pairing themselves.

Comment: long shot but did you ever managed to do this?